# Javascript Function doesn't be called

Tags: javascript

I have to use a function to set the datas before the submit of the form, i use the onclick to call my function but when i click the button all is submitted without pass through the javascript function. 
Here my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Biblioteca Jsp</title>
</head>
<script>
    var checkedBookList = [];

    function checkBook(id) {
        var check = document.getElementById(id);
        checkedBookList[id] = check.checked;
    }

    function submit(){
        document.forms["frBookaBook"].selectedBooks = checkedBookList;
        alert("");
        document.forms["frBookaBook"].submit();
    }
</script>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Elenco libri</h1>
    <hr>
        <table align="center" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th><font color="#822222"> Nome </font></th>
                <th><font color="#822222"> Autore </font></th>
                <th><font color="#822222"> Tipologia </font></th>
            </tr>
            <%  List<MyBook> books = (List<MyBook>)session.getAttribute("bookList");
                String listBook = null;
                if(books!=null && !books.isEmpty()){
                    for (MyBook myBook : books) { %>    
            <tr>
                <td><%=myBook.getBkName() %></td>           
                <td><%=myBook.getBkAuthor() %></td>
                <td><%=myBook.getBkClass() %></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" onChange="checkBook('<%=myBook.getBkID()%>')" 
                            id="<%=myBook.getBkID()%>" name="<%=myBook.getBkName()%>" <% if(myBook.getBkBusy()!=null) { %> disabled="disabled" /> Busy <%} else{ %> /> <%}%> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%      } 
                }%>
        </table>
        <hr>
    <form id="frBookaBook" action="ServletBiblio" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
        <div align="center">
            <input type="hidden"
                    id="actionToDo" name="actionToDo" 
                    value="selectedBooks"/>                 
            <input type="button"
                    id="Prenota" name="Prenota" onclick="submit()"
                    value="Prenota" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you have written onsubmit="return false" ??

Comment: In my opinion: You should simply call your submit function, not on click of a button, but inside onsubmit function, then you call e.preventDefault() if you not want to submit form, and do nothing if you want to process it.

Comment: try this `onclick="return submit();"`. and then return true or false from your function whether you want to submit form or not.

Comment: Change your onclick="submit()" to onclick="javascript: submit();" and remove onsubmit="return false"

Comment: @ParkashKumar `javascript:` is totally useless here...

Comment: I have tried to block the submit with that return false, tryed with onclick="return submit();" but it doesn't works ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**change the name of function submit to submitt or anything**  'submit' is reserved ..

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var checkedBookList = [];
    function checkBook(id) {
        var check = document.getElementById(id);
        checkedBookList[id] = check.checked;
    }

    function submitt(){
        document.forms["frBookaBook"].selectedBooks = checkedBookList;
        alert("");
        document.forms["frBookaBook"].submit();
        return true;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frBookaBook" action="ServletBiblio" method="post" onsubmit="return submitt()">
        <div align="center">
            <input type="hidden"
                    id="actionToDo" name="actionToDo" 
                    value="selectedBooks"/>                 
            <input type="submit"
                    id="Prenota" name="Prenota" 
                    value="Prenota" />
        </div>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alok was faster and has the better answer. (edit)

Rename your function submit() to e.g beforeSubmit(). In this context submit seems to be reserved. You can also think about to use onsubmit event of your form, instead off button click. And may be your button should be type="submit" ...

Answer (score -2):

You have to disable the form before function overloading like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form-licence').submit(function() {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code HTML

```
<input type="button" id="Prenota" name="Prenota" onclick="submit(); return false;" value="Prenota" />
```

Comment: doesn't look like the OP is using Jquery.